# Display a dictionary using ClientRowTemplate in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a dictionary (string, string) that I need to bind within a ClientRowTemplate.  What's the syntax for binding the key and value within the template?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to accomplish is already discussed in great detail on telerik forum.I assume you are using mvc based version since you have not provided any code.

*Dictionary entries cannot be bound.You could show them using template columns.*

**Look into these murtiple ways you can accomplish as discussed on telerik forum**
There are plenty of posts on this issue on telerik forum. I have quote few of notable links below. Suggested option is to use "dynamic" as a model was somewhat successful by person post on first link below.

http://www.telerik.com/forums/grid-with-columns-tied-to-a-dictionary-(sorting-dropdown-menu)#G-VR4zmmJEiB5mZzMMa5mQ

http://www.telerik.com/forums/dictionary-keys-binding